# Insert a data table from MYSQL Database into a HTML table

Tags: c#, html, mysql, sql

I can't seem to find this anywhere. A straight forward way of putting a table from a MYSQL database into a html document as a html . I tried making a long string making a table and iteratively calling the database for the values and then inserting it using Response.Write() to put it in. But it always appears in the top left of the page and I can't seem to format it inside one of my  so it looks incredibly out of place. 
Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can do this?
I am working with aspx/C#
Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to best assist you, you'll need to provide the code your working with and the exact issues you're having. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a table in html and put in the records from your database:

```
<table>
 <thead>      
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Surname</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><% code aspx/C# for column "NAME" in MySQL %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

You can't create (formatting) a layout with aspx/c#. They are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you've ever tried Ajax, but I found it very useful. I don't know whether this helps. I passed on the data as a list and then used accordingly. My data was a list of Account Objects. The url is because I was using MVC so you should update it accordingly.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Accounts/Balance",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var grid = "<table>";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    grid += ("<tr><td>" + data[i].AccountNo + "</td></tr>");
                }
                grid += "</table>";
                $("#tableData").html(grid);
            }

        });
    });
```